# Vue Cli root router is only working

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I have a index.js file inside router folder and here is the code, but the register component is not showing in /register route. Only the HelloWorld component is shown in all the routes.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import Register from '@/components/Register'
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
      path:'/register',
      name:'Register',
      component:Register
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: default mode for vue-router is hash mode use  mode: 'history' in side export https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set mode of router `history`, because default is hash router, it is not fire while history changes.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import Register from '@/components/Register'
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
      path:'/register',
      name:'Register',
      component:Register
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set `history` mode.

Cheers!!

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer: why should one do so, and how?